# Google Cloud Run: Cant connect to Postgress SQL

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run) to upload my existing Django project running locally on sqlite to Google Cloud Run / Postgres.

I have the cloud_sql_proxy service running and can sign into Postgres from the command line.

I am at the point of running the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And I get the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/cloudsql/cgps-registration-2:us-central-1:cgps-reg-2-postgre-sql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

The answer to that questions is Yes, the server is running locally and accepting connections because I can log in with the Postgres client:

```
agerson@agersons-iMac ~ % psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1"  
Password for user postgres: 
psql (14.1, server 13.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
```

I double checked the connection string in my .env file and it has the correct UN / P

Is this scoket not getting created somehow in a previous step?

```
/cloudsql/cgps-registration-2:us-central-1:cgps-reg-2-postgre-sql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Comment: What host did your configure you Django app to connect to ?

Comment: You can run your CLoud SQL proxy in TCP mode or in Socket mode. It seems it is in socket mode, according to your CLI connection. Can you share your Cloud SQL proxy command?

Comment: More questions : Where is the proxy running? Is it in the container with the Cloud Run instance? Or are you using the built-in Cloud Run connectors? When you create the Cloud Run instance, you have the option of specifying a Cloud SQL instance to connect to. Then the Cloud SQL instance, is it configured for public IP, or private IP only? If Private IP only, then you ALSO need to set up the Serverless VPC Connector, which can also be done at deploy time of Cloud Run (although you still need to CREATE the VPC connector before doing that step).

Comment: To add on to Guillaume's question, if using the built-in Cloud Run connector, it only runs in socket mode, not TCP mode.

Comment: It does seam like TCP connections communicate with the cloud SQL proxy just fine and socket ones do not. I tried a socket connection with the Postgres client and it didn't work either. The proxy is running on my workstation. The command I am using is https://gist.github.com/agersoncgps/9d3151abc9d6b875ff23cc1a8ea9771e

I never explicitly created a Cloud Run instance. There's no mention of a step doing that in the official Google tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run) I am following. I was assuming it was being dynamically created by gcloud builds submit and gcloud run deploy.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a mismatch between what the app is looking for and how you're launching the proxy. The error explains the problem.

You're launching the proxy like this with an incorrect region name (us-central):

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances="cgps-registration-2:us-central:cgps-reg-2-postgre-sql=tcp:5432
```

But the app is looking for us-central1. Try this (omitting the `=tcp:5432` to create a Unix socket):

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances="cgps-registration-2:us-central1:cgps-reg-2-postgre-sql
```

Comment: Fixing the region name fixed the issue when running "gcloud builds submit". The Google Cloud run build submits and in the process runs the migrations and creates the tables in the database. However, if I manually trigger "python manage.py migrate" I still get the same socket error. Is this expected?

Comment: Are you starting the Cloud SQL Proxy before running the python script?

Comment: Yes I am starting the Cloud SQL Proxy before running the python script. I read somewhere that "sockets only work locally". I tried removing the =tcp:5432.

Comment: How are you launching the proxy?

Comment: I tried both of the two commands you specified in your answer above

Comment: Just want to additionally double-check if you have updated the region for the database URL in the `.env` file as well? It should also be set to `us-central1`.